# ES6 - `document` is undefined

Tags: javascript, dom, ecmascript-6

Trying to access the document using ES6, which I've usually done as `var document = this.document` to control HTML elements (i.e. pretty important).

In ES6, `this` is undefined (ergo `this.document` doesn't work), and `document` doesn't exist.

Examples & similar questions seem to suggest that this is a non-issue and it works out of the box.  I'm assuming I've missed something painfully obvious or it's a scoping issue.

Comment: Just use `document`?

Comment: In Chrome at least, `document === this.document` is true.

Comment: @lollbirdsey post some code this does actually seem like it should work

Comment: Why are you trying to use `this` at all here? (And given that you are, what is its value?)

Comment: babel defaults to strict mode by default i am assuming thats what you are using, window.document should be what you want.

Comment: Using `this.document` is wrong. What object `this` refers to changes. In a browser you could use `window.document`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has **nothing** to do with EcmaScript 2015.

> In ES6, this is undefined […]

No. You're using [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) (which has been around since ES5). Strict mode makes the global use of `this` equal to `undefined` instead of `window || global`.

You can access `document` either by explicitly mentioning your environment's global variable (in browsers, this is `window`, so you would type `window.document`), or you could just type `document`.

As a side note: In the future, `global` will be the global object in both environments.

Comment: Cheers. Many apologies for the idiocy, I have very little exposure to JS (not a web-dev). Confusing about this being undefined stems from "use strict"  in the ES5 version not being read or something... `document` didn't work by itself. Solution was `window.document`.